# dell edge gateway 3000 GPIO access via registers

Tags: linux-device-driver, gpio

I'd like to be able to access GPIO pins via its register addresses using MMAP. I understand that the Dell edge gateway 3000 uses Intel Atom E3800 processor . I went through its datasheet and it indicates this :

GPIO (PCU) 256 GBA: PCI[B:0,D:31,F:0] + 48h

I'm assuming the GPIO_BASE_ADDRESS is PCI + 48h . I was unable to find the PCI base address though . I was hoping once i get the GPIO_BASE_ADDRESS i can use MMAP and then access the GPIO registers directly to read/write pin values!
Thanks!

Comment: WHY?! Why do you need such an ugly way? Just use existing kernel driver and do whatever you want via */dev/gpio*.

Comment: I understand that the kernel exposes the GPIO pins under /sys/class/gpio/x . The problem with this approach is that if i have to access say 32 pin values at one time , I'd have to do 32 reads which is time consuming. Accessing the registers directly allows me to get all values in 1 or 2 reads . Can you please elaborate on the /dev/gpio method? I'm not familiar with it.Thanks for you reply!

Comment: Precisely you described one issue due to which character device has been introduced and deprecates old sysfs method. Details are in Documentation: _Refer to the examples in tools/gpio/* for an introduction to the new
character device ABI. Also see the userspace header in include/uapi/linux/_. I would add that *libgpiod* project is to make it easy for user space.

Comment: It will still do more reads, but it will be much faster in comparison to old method. Note, what you are trying to do is an ugly hack with problems warranted. Don’t do that way. Note as well, that GPIO is low speed peripheral and can’t be considered for high frequency requirements.

Comment: Doesn't I2C/UART/one-wire work on GPIO which work at high frequencies where they shift in a matter of few milliseconds .  There are multiple boards out there which have 50+ GPIO pins and i have a requirement where i need to query the values of these pins every few milliseconds to check its value ( so that i can monitor its activity when it is doing an I2C/UART/one-wire transaction) .Doing 50+ reads every few milliseconds sounds expensive . I can do the same in 2 register reads! Note I'm using this more for monitoring purposes than actually doing GPIO writes.

Comment: You are mixing up electrical connection with pin function. GPIO has nothing to do with UART or I2C. GPIO was never designed for high frequency requirements. Using anything for real time purposes in non-RT environments is no go.

Comment: It seems you have a long road of learning stuff ahead.

Comment: You're right.. I do :) .. What about libraries like these which enable UART over normal pins https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial . Also lets say I have to read all GPIO pin values every 10 seconds which probably isnt very high frequency . Isn't 50 GPIO pin reads inefficient as well?

Comment: Arduino does not run OS in that case. Bad example. Otherwise as I told you, */dev/gpio* is fast enough, though even deprecated sysfs method would work for you _for every  10 seconds_ case.

Comment: Alright..Thank you so much for all the info so far.. Will check out /dev/gpio ..